# f is continuously differentiable and $f'(0) \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. show that $\int_0^1\frac{1}{f(\sqrt{x})}$ converges

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

a)f is continuously differentiable and $f'(0) \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. show that $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{f(\sqrt{x})}$$ converges

b) now f is continuously differentiable twice and $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$ but $f''(0) \neq 0$ prove that $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{f(\sqrt{x})}$$ diverges

Hi all, This question has to do with Improper integrals convergence. I thought maybe that because we know that the derivative in 0 is not 0 but the value is, the function is monotonous. Then I thought maybe to try and derive the integral but I'm not sure how. A solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to substitute $x = z^2$.

Comment: (a) won't necessarily be true if $f$ has a zero somewhere else in $(0, 1]$.

Comment: @Thomas Hey, that's a good idea but I got stuck $$\int_0^1\frac{2t}{f(t)}$$ then I tried to do integration by parts but it didn't really get me somewhere. Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: You don't have to calculate the integral, you have to show that it converges. For i), note that $f(x) = f(0) + f^\prime(0)x + o(|x|)$. For ii), write down the second order approximation. And take into account @DanielSchepler s comment.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks a lot for the quick reply! I'm not familiar with $o(|x|)$ did you mean a Taylor approximation? if so I'm still not sure how to proceed with that.

Comment: Thats the (ok, one possible) definition of differentiability. Of course you can also use Taylors theorem.

Comment: Oh right! now I get what you mean. I'll try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that $f$ does not go to 0 on any other point of the interval, so we just have to worry of what happens near 0. On both cases use substitution $u = \sqrt{x}$ then the integral we are interested in becomes

$
2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{u}{f\left(u\right)} du.
$

Now, for item a, you get

$
\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{f\left(u\right)}{u} = f'\left(0\right) \neq 0
$

So you can find a lower bound for $\left|\frac{f\left(u\right)}{u}\right|$ in a neighboorhood of $0$, which gives you an upper bound for $\left|\frac{u}{f\left(u\right)}\right|$ and from this you can conclude.

For item b, you get using L'Hopital

$
\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{f\left(u\right)}{u^{2}} = \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{f'\left(u\right)}{2u} = f''\left(0\right) \neq 0
$

Now we have an upper bound (because the limit exists) and an lower bound, but for $\left|\frac{f\left(u\right)}{u^{2}}\right|$. I am going to assume this is positive, the negative case is analogous, so there are $\epsilon,c,C >0$ such that

$
c > \frac{f\left(u\right)}{u^{2}} > C 
\ \forall u \in \left[0,\epsilon\right],
$

hence

$
2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{u}{f\left(u\right)}du > 
2\int_{0}^{\epsilon} \frac{u}{f\left(u\right)}du > 
2\int_{0}^{\epsilon} \frac{u}{cu^{2}}  du = 2\int_{0}^{\epsilon} \frac{du}{cu} = +\infty
$

Comment: that would be $=\infty$ in the last inequality and not $>$

Comment: @Thomas you are right, I just edited

Comment: @RaulFernandesHorta Thanks a lot for the reply!. In task b, why did you look for the limit $\lim_{u \to 0}$ $\frac{f(u)}{u^2}$ and not $\lim_{u \to 0}$ $\frac{f(u)}{u}$?

Comment: @EliBrown I wanted to make $f''\left(0\right)$ appear somehow and I noticed I could use L'Hopital, but for the second derivative you need to use it twice, and with $\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{f\left(u\right)}{u}$ you can only use it once, that's why I used $u^{2}$ instead of $u$.